# Simple question to check property of Normal Distributions.

Tags: probability-distributions

So I was preparing for an entrance test and the study material provided by the institution has a lot of mistakes .Please forgive me if this seems off topic.

I just know high school maths and I am studying Normal Distributions for the first time and I want to ensure whether there is a misprint in the book for this fact in the image(in red box).

[image]

For all I know this is a contradiction simply due to misprint.Am I right or wrong.And if wrong,why?

P.S.:Also any other online resource to learn normal distributions would be helpful if anyone knows one.

Comment: 14.26 is correct and 14.31 is indeed a misprint.

Comment: @drhab Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you mean $z\sim\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$?

Comment: @robjohn I did not understand what you mean.I thought there was a mistake in the book that is shown in red boxes.The other things I already have understood.

Comment: That was answered by drhab, but I was just looking at your formula that says $z=x-\mu/\sigma$, which looks wrong, also.  It could have been a typo in the book, or a typo in your MathJax.

Comment: @robjohn You mean it looks like that $\sigma$ is just below $\mu$ only.Well that is  given correct on the succeeding page and also by the way that is an image from the book ,I did not use MathJax for that.

Comment: Doh! It is an image. That answers my question; it is a typo in the book.